# Выделить часть текста в TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

Мой текст в TextView генерируется из различных int

```
explaintextView.setText ( Html.fromHtml ( ( problem ) + ( index01 ) + ( notodo ) + ( index02 ) + ( todo ) + ( index03 ) + ( result ) + ( index04 ) ) );
```

В параметрах String сделаны пробелы 
`<br> и <tittle>`, но не работает выделение текста жирным `<b>`

```
<string name="problem" formatted="false"> <![CDATA[ <title> <b> Смысл проблемы </b>  </title> <br/><br/> ]]>
</string>
```

Как это исправить?
Или есть способ более корректной генерации такого TextView (читал, что  Html.fromHtml) нежелательно

Comment: Есть строка String problem = getResources().getString(R.string.problem); и нет выделения жирным?

Comment: @iramm.Добавление строки String problem = getResources()..... значительно улучшило часть кода, но проблему, увы, не решило

Comment: Что значит "генерируется из различных int"? Что это за целые значения?

Comment: С обычными числами у меня было выделение жирным.

Comment: @iramm. попробую на тестовом приложении. Textview у меня генерируется из случайных сток ресурса string, которые помещены в массив

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы дополнили ваш вопрос: привели строковые ресурсы и то, как на их основе что-то генерируется. Тогда бы мы смогли бы вам помочь эффективнее

Comment: Да, вы полностью правы все работает! Это я не заметил настройки TextView в Activity.xml, где стояло "bold" для всего textview

Answer (score 0):

Вообще,я понимаю, что мой мой вопрос был не до конца корректен, но мне удалось решить проблему таким способом

```
 String problem ="<big>ПРИЧИНА ПРОБЛЕМЫ:<br/><br/></big>";
                String nottodo = "<big>ЧЕГО НЕ СЛЕДУЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ:<br/><br/></big>";
                String todo = "<big>ЧТО СЛЕДУЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ:<br/><br/></big>";
                String result = "<big>РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:<br/><br/></big>";
```

Textview, соответственно, было таким:

```
explaintextView.setText ( Html.fromHtml ( (( problem ) + ( index01 ) + ( nottodo ) + ( index02 ) + ( todo ) + ( index03 ) + ( result ) + ( index04 ) )) );
```

index01-04 это текстовые области,которые генерируются в зависимости от случайным образом сгенерированных Imageview